# Design Pattern for extensible entity

Tags: design-patterns

I am developing an application for hotel reservation 
i am have a model called "Hotel" 
It has name, description, rate, at the moment 
i want to design it in a way to be able to plugin more simple and complex properties into the model 
For example address, amenities,

or user model , right now it just have name and lastname user and password , but i want to be able to add other properties to it in plugable way .

is there any pattern for that ?
Builder pattern / observer pattern?

Comment: it is not clear at all what your question is

Comment: Have you thought about inheritance? I've heard this pattern is useful sometimes. You could also use this funky thing called composition to build your entities from components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Martin Fowler's description of [Dynamic Properties (pdf)](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/properties.pdf) and [User Defined Fields](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html). You can use something as simple as a hash table (aka dictionary) to hold your dynamic properties, but depending on the language (and the implementation) your "class schema" won't be so clear.